# image density of foreground

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr

I want to get the density of the foreground.To be specific,first I need to to get the region of the foreground,inside the blue curve.Then use pixels inside the region to compute density.Obviously it cannot be solved by threshold or contour methods.It is a part of a Chinese character,so OCR may be useful,I don't know.Any advice?Thanks.

Now I have some idea.Randomly select 100 dots or more,than compute the average pixels around these dots,say radius is 100 or other.Hope this would be a estimate of the density.Is there some algorithm to achieve this?

**Original Image**
[image: original image]

**Result expected**
[image: need to be realized]

Comment: Have you tried using *"morphological dilation"* of the lighter strokes to *"fill them out"*? http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_morphology.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-xx-applications-plot-morphology-py

Answer (score 1):

Dilation works really well for your application like @Mark Setchell already pointed out in the comments.

First, use the `dilate` function to fill the gap in between your components. I used a quadratic kernel of size 35:

[image: dilated image]

Next, use the `threshold` function to obtain a binary image:

[[image: binary image[2]]

Finally, use the `findContours` function to calculate the image contours and draw them using `drawContours`. The result will look very similar to your desired output:

[image: output image]

You may have to change some parameters (mainly the dilation kernel size) depending on your input, but this should generally be the best approach to your problem.

Comment: Cool - thanks for doing the hard bit and sharing it!

Comment: Thanks！Very useful and awesome method.